# Pandas словарь внутри строки

Tags: pandas, dict

У меня есть датафрейм, в котором в столбце 'source' содержатся данные такого типа:
'{"source":"Referral","domain":"www.yyy.com"}', '{"utm_source":"board","source":"Referral","domain":"www.yyy.ru"}'

Мне нужно создать новый столбец, в котором будет значение ключа source и utm_source, т.е. Referral, board, etc.

Пробовала так:
Вариант 1

list_values = []

for value in new_wordpress['source'].values:

```
list_values.append(value['source'])
```

Output: invalid index to scalar variable

вариант 2:

new_wordpress["new"] = (new_wordpress["source"]
.apply(lambda x: x.get("source")
if isinstance(x, dict)
else np.nan))

Output: array([nan])

Comment: возможно это потому, что в "source" у вас строки а не словари

Comment: И как тогда выдернуть значения?

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'source':['{"source":"Referral","domain":"www.yyy.com"}', '{"utm_source":"board","source":"Referral","domain":"www.yyy.ru"}']})
df

                                              source
0       {"source":"Referral","domain":"www.yyy.com"}
1  {"utm_source":"board","source":"Referral","dom...
```

```
df['source'].apply(lambda x: eval(x)).apply(lambda x: pd.Series({'new_sourse': x.get('source'), 'utm_source': x.get('utm_source')}))


    new_sourse  utm_source
0   Referral    None
1   Referral    board
```

Comment: Output: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object

Comment: ну что ж, тогда проверьте что же за данные у вас в этом столбце. как видите в моем примере это сработало. значит у вас что-то другое.

Comment: source  80382 non-null  object

Comment: видимо вам следует дополнить свой вопрос минимально воспроизводимым набором данных. иначе вам мало кто сможет помочь.